# Getting "No virtual method getTag(Ljava/lang/String;)" error when calling suspended method using viewModelScope.launch inside ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to call a suspended method through `viewModelScope.launch()` but the app crashes as soon as the method gets called.

I should point out that i'm using latest version of androidX stable libraries.
For ViewModel and LiveData however, i'm using the alpha version which is `2.2.0-alpha02`.
And of course the Retrofit version is `2.6.0`, so it should be fine to mark it's functions as suspended.

Also, the variables are initialized using Koin.

Log:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getTag(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Landroidx/lifecycle/ViewModel; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel' appears in /data/app/co.nilin.varabank-lUNWj0JGUm_fCoYkMmbbJg==/base.apk)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelKt.getViewModelScope(ViewModel.kt:36)
        at co.nilin.varabank.home.HomeViewModel.fetchRates(HomeViewModel.kt:18)
        at co.nilin.varabank.home.HomeActivity$init$2.onClick(HomeActivity.kt:27)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Retrofit web service:

```
interface BankCalculatorWebService {
    @GET("auto/bank-gateway/general/{bank}/currencies")
    suspend fun fetchCurrencyRates(@Path("bank") bank: String): Response<CurrencyRateResponse>
}
```

Repository:

```
class BankCalculatorRepositoryImpl(
    private val webService: BankCalculatorWebService
) : BankCalculatorRepository {
    override suspend fun fetchRates(): List<CurrencyRateDTO> {
        val list = ArrayList<CurrencyRateDTO>()
        val response = webService.fetchCurrencyRates(Bank.getDefaultBank().swiftCode)
        response.ifSuccessful { response ->
            response.items.forEach {
                list.add(CurrencyRateDTO.fromCurrencyRate(it))
            }
        }
        return list
    }
}
```

View model:

```
class HomeViewModel(
    private val repository: BankCalculatorRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    val rates = MutableLiveData<List<CurrencyRateDTO>>()

    fun fetchRates() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val response = repository.fetchRates()
            rates.postValue(response)
        }
    }
}
```

Code inside the activity

```
viewModel.rates.observe(this) {
    Toast.makeText(this, it.size, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

button.setOnClickListener {
    viewModel.fetchRates()
}
```

Comment: Sounds like version mismatch across the jetpack libraries

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by dependencies on different versions of the `androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel` class polluting your classpath (probably with both the 2.2.0 and 2.0.0 versions). It's usually due to transitive dependencies from outdated libraries. For me it was the support-v4 library causing it.

Run `./gradlew app:dependencies` to see your tree, and then look for transitive dependencies on `ViewModel`. For those libraries that are pulling in the old version, either update them or exclude the `ViewModel` dependency for them:

```
implemenation ("com.<library>") {
    exclude group:'androidx.lifecycle', module:'lifecycle-viewmodel'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. I couldn't find any solution rather than implement viewModelScope myself. Your HomeViewModel code will look like

```
 class HomeViewModel(
    private val repository: BankCalculatorRepository
) : ViewModel() {

private val viewModelJob = SupervisorJob()
protected val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)

val rates = MutableLiveData<List<CurrencyRateDTO>>()

    fun fetchRates() {
        uiScope.launch {
            val response = repository.fetchRates()
            rates.postValue(response)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Cancel all coroutines when the ViewModel is cleared
     */
    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        uiScope.coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
    }
}
```